# Pricing issues with pounds and pence!

Tags: php, mysql

At the moment I store prices for products in the database as a pence number. So 4321 in the database means £43.21.

Then when reading it out, I divide by 100 to get it in pound and pence format.

However, I have a problem.

If the price is 4320, the returned value is 43.2 without the 0.

How can I get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: number_format or sprintf("%0.2f", $your_price);

Comment: Any reason you're not storing prices as `FLOAT`s in your database...?

Comment: Storing prices as float is a no-go. Try `DECIMAL` @Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format strings with [sprintf](http://si.php.net/sprintf)

See example 9:

```
<?php
$money1 = 68.75;
$money2 = 54.35;
$money = $money1 + $money2;
// echo $money will output "123.1";
$formatted = sprintf("%01.2f", $money);
// echo $formatted will output "123.10"
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?
  echo money_format("%i", 1234.5) 
  //Output: 1234.50
?>
```

You can use [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php).

Answer (score 1):

[`money_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) should do the trick. Alternatively [`number_format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) or the powerful [`printf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
echo number_format($float, 2, '.', '');
```

and for pretty printing of large values:

```
echo number_format($float, 2, '.', ',');
```